# Laravel Query. Obtain in Eloquent only totals > 0

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query:

```php
public static function totalByAgent(int $agentId)
{
    return PropertyListing::select(
        DB::raw('SUM(property_listing.rental) as rental'),
        DB::raw('SUM(property_listing.sale) as sale'),
        'property_category.name as category_name',
        'property_category.id as category_id'
    )->join(
        'property_category',
        'property_category.id',
        'property_listing.category_id'
    )->where('agent_id', $agentId)->groupBy('property_category.id')->get();
}
```

With this query I obtain the sum of properties for sale and sum of properties to rent group by property categories. But If some property have only properties for sale and 0 to rent I obtain 0 in sum of rents.

I tried adding:

```php
->having('sale', '>', 0)->get()
```

after groupBy. this hides the rents if they had.

Any idea?

Best regards

Comment: Did you test the sql query directly in your database? without Eloquent. Then try to pass it to Eloquent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this query works for me:

```
      return Property::published()->select(DB::raw('SUM(property.rental) as rental'),
                                    DB::raw('SUM(property.sale) as sale'),
                                    'property_category.name as category_name',
                                    'property_category.id as category_id')
          ->join('property_category', 'property_category.id', 'property.category_id')
          ->whereExists(function ($query) use ($agentId){
                      $query->select('property_listing.agent_id')
                            ->from('property_listing')
                            ->whereRaw('property.id = property_listing.property_id')
                            ->where('property_listing.agent_id', $agentId);
                            })->published()
         ->groupBy('property_category.id')->get();
```